# How to solve $10^{x^2+x}+\log{x} = 10^{x+1}$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

In one of my recent exam, I was ask to solve this:
$$
10^{x^2+x}+\log{x} = 10^{x+1}
$$

My attempt to solve it was:

$$
10^{x^2+x}+\log{x}       = 10^{x+1}         \\
\log{x}=10^{x+1}-10^{x^2+x}  \\
\log{x} = 10^{x+1}(1-10^x)   \\
\log(\log{x})=(x+1)+\log(1-10^x)    \\
$$

At this point I got stuck because I don't know how to solve an equation with double logs.

Comment: Hint: find a (rather obvious) solution and prove there are no other.

Comment: The second last statement seems wrong to me. It won't allow the obvious solution $x = 1$.

Comment: I agree with the previous comment, you are going way too quickly when taking logarithm. Pay attention... In order to prove that there is only one solution, like suggested, you can study the dericative of the function.

Answer (score 3):

Note that $x=1$ is obviously a solution. We prove that this is the only solution.

Suppose that $x>1$. Then $x^2>1$, so $x^2+x>x+1$. Exponentiating both sides we get that:

$$10^{x^2+x}>10^{x+1}$$

since $\log(x)>0$ when $x>1$, then we also have:

$$10^{x^2+x}+\log(x)>10^{x+1}$$

so there are no solutions in this range.

Similarly, when $0<x<1$, then $x^2+x<x+1$, so

$$10^{x^2+x}<10^{x+1}$$

and because $\log(x)<0$ in this range, then:

$$10^{x^2+x}+\log(x)<10^{x+1}$$

so there are no solutions in this range either.

The equation is undefined when $x\leq0$, so this proves that $x=1$ is the only solution.

Answer (score 2):

If $x > 1$, then $x^2 + x > x + 1> 0$, and $\log x > 0$, thus $LHS > RHS$, and if $0 < x < 1$, then $0 <x^2 + x < x + 1$, and $\log x < 0$, thus $LHS < RHS$. When $x = 1$, both sides equal to $100$. Thus the only answer is $x = 1$.

Answer (score 2):

In your manipulation of the equation you factored the powers of $10$ incorrectly. Correction:

$$10^{x^2+x} + \log(x) = 10^{x+1}\\\log(x) = 10^{x+1}(1-10^{x^2 - 1})$$

---

We know that $x > 0$ for $\log(x)$ to be defined.

Case ($0 < x < 1$): $\log(x) < 0 < 10^{x+1}(1-10^{x^2-1})$

Case ($x = 1$): $\log(1) = 0 = 10^2(1-10^0)$

Case ($x > 1$): $\log(x) > 0 > 10^{x+1}(1-10^{x^2-1})$

Thus the only solution is $\boxed{x = 1}$